# Can the Lenovo ThinkPad P1 - P2000 drive 3 2560x1440 displays?

Tags: laptop, thinkpad

I'm not very familiar with modern laptops and thunderbolt. The [ThinkPad P1 - P2000](https://www.lenovo.com/gb/en/laptops/thinkpad/p-series/ThinkPad-P1/p/20MDCTO1WWENGB2) comes with a NVIDIA Quadro P2000 4GB GDRR5 128bits and two thunderbolt ports and an hdmi display:

[image]

1. Power in
2. Intel® Thunderbolt™ 3
3. HDMI 2.0
4. Mini Gigabit Ethernet
5. 3.5mm Mic/headphone combo jack

Would this computer be able to drive 3 2560x1440 displays that have display port and/or hdmi ports (so, no daisy chaining thunderbolt)? Can each thunderbolt drive 
 one monitor while the HDMI drives another? Would there be any issues with colors, refresh rate, resolution, etc. not matching? Would I otherwise need a docking station that can go from one to three thunderbolt ports?

Answer (score 0):

The [NVIDIA Quadro P2000](https://www.pny.com/nvidia-quadro-p2000)
is said to be able to drive up to four 5K (5120 x 2880 at 60Hz) displays natively.
So no problem on this side.

If your displays have dual Thunderbolt ports,
you only need one Thunderbolt port for all the displays using
[Thunderbolt Daisy Chaining](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/thunderbolt-daisychain-connect-mac-accessories/).

[image]

If your displays are not Thunderbolt-capable, you will need a dock.
For example see
[Top 7 Best Thunderbolt 2 Docks 2018 + Editors Pick](https://www.omnicoreagency.com/best-thunderbolt-2-docks/).

I would still advise to have one monitor directly connected, if you have one
unused Thunderbolt port.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Daisy chaining wouldn't be an option  as I couldn't find a single monitor that supported it (within my budget). Not even Apple is making those monitors anymor. I added some relevant information to the question.

Comment: You may put one monitor on the HDMI port, and on the Thunderbolt port a modest dock that has two suitable ports for your monitors.

Comment: Would there be any noticeable differences between monitors running of thunderbolt and monitors running from hdmi? For example: refresh rates, resolution, colors looking differently, Windows not detecting their presence/absense correctly when comnig from hybernation and breaking the windows layout, moving them around, etc.

Comment: Not according to the on the Thunderbolt specifications. You could probably also put USB devices on the same dock.

Comment: You mean no difference?

Comment: Thunderbolt is supposed to be able to do much more than that. Never used it, but its technical specs are very impressive.

Comment: Yes, I understand that thunderbolt is like a supped up USB. But for example, if I had three monitors and I would have to chose to connect 2 with VGA and 1 with DVI or 3 with VGA I would go with 3 with VGA.

Comment: That depends on the monitor and the dock. For high-res monitors DisplayPort is the best.